# Autocomplete with $.getJSON - CAN'T DISPLAY "No results" message

Tags: ajax, jquery-autocomplete, getjson, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have problem with Autocomplete with `$.getJSON`...
I need display "No results" message but i cant because `data.length` isn't `== 0`.
I know `$.getJSON` return object and that is why `data.length` isn't `== 0`... 
Anybody have solution?

```
    $.getJSON(restUrl, function (data) 
    {   
    var suggestions = [];
    no_results = !data || data.length == 0;
    if (!no_results)
    {
        $.each(data, function (key,val) 
        {
        suggestions.push({                      
                label: val.name,
                mail: val.mail,
                adress: val.adress
            });
        });
    }
    else
        {
        suggestions.push({   
        label: "No Results found."
        });
        }
    response(suggestions);
    });
},
```

Comment: You may return *false* from the restUrl and check it in callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working!

```
    $.getJSON(restUrl, function (data) 
    {   
        response($.map(data, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item.name,
                        mail: item.mail,
                        address: item.address
                        }
                }));
    })
    .error(function() {
        var suggestions = [];
        suggestions.push({                      
                label: "No Results"
                });
        response(suggestions);
    });
```